# Substraction of line feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, features, overlapping-features, tools

[image]

I have two overlapping line features. The blue line is a intercepted feature outputted of the red line (and another polygon feature).

I need to get only the red line parts where there is no overlapping with the blue line. How would you solve this?

I'm using QGIS 3.26.2 i already tried "Symmetric Difference".

Comment: What software are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I´m using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5 (Standard) and Qgs3.26.2
i tried "symetric difference"

Comment: Please decide whether it is ArcGIS Pro or QGIS that you wish to ask about in this particular question, and then use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.